# Shows specific divs on scroll with non javascript browser support

Tags: jquery

I am trying to modify below Script to make it more friendly for users who disabled Javascript. The code below set opacity of all divs to 0 and 1 on scroll position. I want to hide specific divs by manually adding class 'hideme' and show them on scroll.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

/* Hide all elements outside the visible window */
$('body *').each( function(){

    var top_of_object = $(this).position().top;
    var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

    if( bottom_of_window < top_of_object  ){

        $(this).addClass('hideme').css({'opacity':'0'});

    }

});

/* Every time the window is scrolled ... */
$(window).scroll( function(){

    /* Check the location of the desired elements */
    $('.hideme').each( function(i){

        var bottom_of_object = $(this).position().top + $(this).outerHeight();
        var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();


            if( bottom_of_window > ( bottom_of_object + 20 )  ){

                $(this).removeClass('hideme').animate({'opacity':'1'},500);

            }

    }); 

});

 });
```

I figured out how to specify selected divs, just change below code

$('body *').each( function(){

to

$('.div-class,.another-div-class').each( function(){

Comment: "I am trying to modify below javascript to make it more friendly for users who disable javascript." If they have JavaScript disabled then the code won't execute at all; there's no way to make it "more friendly" for them.

Answer (score 0):

As noted by Anthony in the comments, that code went execute at all if a user has disabled JavaScript as it is, in itself, JavaScript.

You probably need to reverse your logic and construct your HTML page so it would be fine with no JavaScript, and then in your JavaScript add anything extra or use the JavaScript to hide/change parts of the DOM to make it better for people with JavaScript.

I feel inclined (but know I will be launched upon by all the non-JS people out there) to also point out that you need to weigh up whether the minority of non-Javascripters are worth the extra time and effort it will take you, or whether you could just use our friend the `<noscript>` tag to tell them that parts of your site require JavaScript to display correctly. Sure, it is good practice to make your site degrade gracefully, but remember that actually having a site working is probably more important than making sure every case works for every person. I've seen too many people fall into the trap of trying to please everyone and never actually releasing their product!

I know this doesn't really give you any solid answers but it might be a good starting point for you.

Comment: I focused on non Javascript support more than actual issue. I know the script works fine while Javascript is disabled. What I want to achieve is applying fade in 'show' div effect in specific areas of design. Currently, effect applies to every area of *body*.